# Upload profile picture on Microsoft with selenium, python ()

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, selenium-chromedriver

So, what I'm trying to do is to automate a process which opens the Microsoft login page, enters the login information and then logs in. After that it clicks on the profile and then clicks on change profile picture button.
Now, I'm having trouble with the next part....which is to upload a picture and set it as profile picture.
I searched all over the internet but can't find a solution.

My code till now is -

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\verma\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
action = ActionChains(browser)

#1. Open Microsoft Login Page
browser.get('https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/?wa=wsignin1.0')
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"mectrl_headerPicture"))).click()

#2. Login with Username and Password
user = (By.ID,"i0116")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(user)).send_keys("emailid@outlook.com")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"idSIButton9"))).click()
password = (By.ID,"i0118")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(password)).send_keys("password")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"idSIButton9"))).click()

#3. Click on Profile and then Click on Change Picture
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"mectrl_headerPicture"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"mectrl_currentAccount_picture_profile_picture"))).click()

#4. Upload Picture

time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

What I have tried is -

```
#4. Upload Picture
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"id__62"))).click()
```

The windows file chooser is not popping up. My guess is that I gave wrong ID for "Choose File" button/link to selenium and that's why it gives TimeoutException since it cant find the element.
But I cant seem find the correct ID. I also want to know how to upload the picture after the File Chooser pops up successfully.

EDIT: Screenshot of the HTML code (Through Inspect)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq6gw.png)

Comment: Share your HTML code in text format for better understanding.

Comment: @cruisepandey sharing the whole HTML code is gonna be hectic....but i have now included a screenshot of HTML (inspect). The highlighted part shows the id

Comment: okay, I logged in with my own creds, look likes we need to switch to a different tab and then in that new tab I see a input tag with file attribute. will revert back.

Comment: @cruisepandey so what do i have to do here?? i'm sorry i dont understand

Comment: Are you able to click on `Add a photo` link ?

Comment: @cruisepandey no, thats the main problem here. I cant click on "Add a photo".

Comment: I have given a solution, let me know if there's any more concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few steps that you need to follow in order to upload a pic :

1. you need to switch driver focus to new tab
2. Click on Add a photo.
3. Upload a pic.
4. Assert Successful Message.

**Code :**

```
#4. Upload Picture
windows_before  = browser.current_window_handle
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"mectrl_currentAccount_picture_profile_picture"))).click()  # this is from #3
windows_after = browser.window_handles
new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
browser.switch_to.window(new_window)
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='profile.profile-page.profile-pic-section.edit-picture']").click()
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='button[id='profile.edit-picture.upload-button']']").click()
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys("path of the file to be uploaded")
#Assert your msg
```

Comment: thanx a lot....although this exact code didnt work.....at first i just copied your code but it gave an error that "button is not clickable" and file chooser was not opening.....but your code gave me some ideas.....so i wrote 
`browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='profile.edit-picture.upload-button']").click()`
This opened the file chooser.....but then i realized that opening the file chooser is not necessary....the last line in your code works as it is.... i.e
`browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\verma\\Downloads\\1.jpg")`

Comment: great ! Remember if you see any input field with `type='file'`, you can do send_keys to uplaod a file.

Comment: i'll remember that.....thanx a lot for your help. You saved me.

Comment: @AnshulVerma : Even it worked for me too. Let me know if you have any more concerns

Comment: yeah...its working....i figured out what to do.....and its all thanks to you. @cruisepandey